# Function that change args with php? 

Tags: php

I dont know what we call this, but it will be something like this

```
$args = 1

function rendercomments($args,$usersholder = NULL ){
    $args = $args + 1;
    // missing
    return true;
}

changeargs($args);
$userholder = 2
```

Can we do something like that? 
Someway to make $args append to $usersholder without returning it?

Comment: plesae tell if you dont understand, i mean something to make the args dynamic or something like that, it would be useful if we want to append like errors etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all you need is to define your arguments *"by reference"* by using the ampersand (`&`).

```
function rendercomments(&$args, $usersholder = NULL){
  $args += 1;
  return true;
}

$args = 1;
rendercomments($args);
echo $args; // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are asking for is to update the `$userholder` variable while inside the called function.

If so, you have two options:

1. Create a class that contains the `$userholder` and the `changeargs($args);` should be inside that class and you can just use the `$this` keyword to apply any changes to the `$userholder` object and the changes will continue outside of the `changeargs()` function.
2. Pass into the `changeargs()` function a reference to the `$userholder` variable so that you are modifying that variable the whole time.